# Doctrine2: schema-tool Mappedsuperclass problem

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-orm

```
baseclass.php
---------------------------------------------------------
/**
 *
 * @MappedSuperclass
 *
 */
class Baseclass {
    // code

}
```

---

```
 aclass.php
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 /**
  * @Entity @Table(name="something")
  */
 class Aclass extends Baseclass{
    // code

 }
```

with this code above, when I try to execute

> doctrine schema-tool:create

I get BaseClass not found error, but when I change the name of the
Aclass name to Dclass (alphabetically after BaseClass ) everything
works fine. I remember seeing some bug report somewhere that says,
it's something to do with alphabetical order, but I can not find that
report and I wonder if there is a solution for this problem? I use
doctrine 2.0 stable by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up autoloading of your classes in your doctrine-cli.php script.